# coupling - C++ web or GUI desktop apps

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, coupling, wt

How to handle coupling in advanced C++ applications?

Can we use finished code for web application, written (for e.g.) with Witty, and make console application with it? ...or change it to desktop application with GUI made with Qt?

yes / no and why?

how to make it most possible and easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your application was developed. Have you used design patterns and other techniques like MVC in the web application? If so, I think you can develop console application without doing many changes. If you haven´t, you will have to refactor some code.

Comment: can I use WT only for View layer and leave rest of my code just in pure C++?

Comment: Yes, which means that your business logic stays at the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible with some of the components from QT like QmlApplicationViewer or Html5ApplicationViewer, if your application is not to big or if does not require many changes or new functionality I would say go for it, otherwise I would suggest to consider another alternative.

--I would suggest to have a look at Titanium studio, it might be what you are looking for (http://www.appcelerator.com/)